# React, two components running two timeouts to dismount; same unmount gets called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**TL;DR**: This is happening: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/204124/
Why do they both disappear at the same time? The styles that should only be applied to one component seem to be applied to both.

This version: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/204131/ where they are made red instead of the opacity changing makes the problem more clear; the red style gets applied to both notifications, even though the timeout only set off for one.

When the Notification component mounts it sets a timeout for a variable delay:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
        let timeout = parseInt(this.props.decay) || 2000
        this.setState({ 
            dismissTimeout: setTimeout(() => {
                this.fadeOutFunction();
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.dismiss();
                }, 125)
            }, timeout)
        })  
    }   
}
```

The fade out animation will happen over the course of 100 ms, and then the component will be dismounted:

```
fadeOutFunction = () => {
    let opacity = Math.floor(this.state.style.opacity * 10) 
    if ( opacity > 0) {
        opacity -= 1;  
        setTimeout(() => { this.fadeOutFunction() }, 10) 
    }   
    let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state.style)
    newState.opacity = opacity / 10
    this.setState({ style: newState })
}
```

The dismiss function is hooked up to this function in the parent component which is managing an array of 'models' of data for the Notification component:

```
dismiss = () => {
    this.props.dismiss(this.props.code);
} 

// in parent
dismissNotification = (code) => {
    this.setState({ notifications: this.state.notifications.filter (
        n => n.code != code
    )})
}
```

Two notifications are set, one with 2000 decay and one with 5000 decay.

When the first component finishes fading out some really strange behavior happens; both components lose their opacity (set to 0), and the dismount function is called for the wrong component... What's crazy is that the fadeOut function continues calling for the 'dismounted' component (the 5000ms one, that is still in the DOM) leading to the error:

`Warning: Can't call setState (or forceUpdate) on an unmounted component.`

But what's really perplexing to me is that, if I inspect `dismissNotification`, it's filtering out the correct notification.

**Update**: the jsFiddle now reproduces the error: 
https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/204124/

But there isn't any issue! And looking at my code I don't think there are any significant differences, in fact, when I change the fadeOut function to instead 'set the component to red':

```
makeRedFunction = () => {
    this.setState({ style: {backgroundColor: "red"} })
}
```

The components change their style at the right times, and dismiss properly with no errors.

I'm sorry this is somewhat vague :/ and I really wish I knew how to get more of the right information but.. why would setting the opacity not trigger an error on codefiddle but trigger one in my app? Why does the opacity lead to this strange, cross-component behavior but the color doesn't?

Am I missing some dependency critical for animation in my project? I've seen that there are animation libraries but with this simple stuff I'd rather just code it myself.

**Edit: **
The rendering for my parent component

```
            {
                this.state.notifications.map( (n, idx) => {                                                                                                                       
                    return <Notification                                                                                                                                          
                        key={idx}                                                                                                                                                 
                        code={n.code}                                                                                                                                             
                        decay={n.decay}
                        dismiss={ () =>{this.dismissNotification(n.code)}}                                                                                                                        
                    > 
                        { n.message }                                                                                                                                             
                    </Notification>                                                                                                                                               
                })                                                                                                                                                                
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a logical error in the Notification component :

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.fadeOutFunction();
  setTimeout(() => {  // <--- This part is uneccessary
   this.dismiss();
  }, 125)
}, timeout)
```

Change it to :

```
class Notification extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        style: { opacity: 1 }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    let timeout = parseInt(this.props.decay) || 2000

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.fadeOutFunction();
    }, timeout)     
  }

  fadeOutFunction = () => {
    let opacity = Math.floor(this.state.style.opacity * 10)
    if (opacity > 0) {
        opacity -= 1
      setTimeout( () => { this.fadeOutFunction() }, 10)
    }
    let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state.style)
    newState.opacity = opacity / 10
    this.setState({ style: newState })
  }

  dismiss = () => {
    this.props.dismiss(this.props.code)
  }

  render () {
    return(
         <div style={this.state.style}>{this.props.children}</div>
    )
  }
}
```